# Testing similarity of proportions across groups of samples- is ANOVA the right method?

Tags: distributions, anova, population, compositional-data

Generally, I'm looking for the correct way to test if samples of a certain population over time tend to have the same proportional distribution more or less e.g. if the amount of certain race in a population sticks to 20% of the population, regardless if the population is 5 at time t = 0 and 100 at time t = 2. I think an example would best describe my dilemma.

Say I have a population of animals, consisting of owls, rabbits, and foxes. I collect information about the population over time, so the first sample of the population is 6 owls, 15 rabbits, and 30 foxes. When I record a second sample, the population has 10 owls, 23 rabbits, and 47 foxes. The third is 13 owls, 29 rabbits and 62 foxes. I would like to see if the distribution among the first, second, and third sample are similarly distributed, meaning if 6/46, 10/80, 13/104 somehow represent the mean of the percentage of owls in the sample population.

I know I can do an ANOVA to test owls at 6, 10, and 13 if I were to test the means, but the population is growing over time. So, testing the to see if the mean among the three samples (that each contain 1 data point) would be pointless if the population is growing. Can I test the fractions 6/46, 10/80, and 13/104 to see if the proportion of owls is the same?

I can run the same ANOVA to test if rabbits and foxes have a mean proportion that is representation of the population. However, if I wanted to test all three populations together, is there another test that I can use to see if, together, the population samples support a certain proportion breakdown.

Comment: Look into compositional data analysis. This is a special data type that cannot be analyzed with traditional methods in a straightforward way.

Comment: It will help if you can say what your predictor variables are, but it seems like you could do a multinomial logistic regression of the animal categories on the “before” and “after” groups. This is totally analogous to ANOVA for your categorical variable of interest.